# android - can not load generated native library

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I am currently working on an android library in android studio 3.0.1 with cpp support.
Therefor I started with a little test to check the functionality and get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no native-lib in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at com.pmdtec.testproject.TestClass.<clinit>(TestClass.java:6)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:107)
```

My Source Files are:

TestProject/app/src/java/com/example/TestClass.java

```
package com.example;

public class TestClass
{
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new TestClass().helloNative();
    }

    native void helloNative();
}
```

TestProject/app/src/cpp/native-lib.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_TestClass_helloNative(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance)
{
    // implement later
}
```

And I also added "android.enableAapt2=false" to the TestProject/gradle.properties because the gradle build got this error (This error does not occure anymore. I just wanted to document that, and why I added the property to gradle.properties)

```
Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
Information:Gradle: BUILD FAILED in 4s
Information:15.01.2018 11:46 - Compilation completed with 5 errors and 0 warnings in 6s 736ms
Error:Gradle: failed to create directory 'D:\workspace\TestProject\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\com\example'.
Error:Gradle: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Gradle: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Gradle: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

The files that are not shown here are the generated files.
So my question is, does anyone know why I get the error mentiont at the top of this post?

---

Some more details:

The resulting .apk contains the following files

```
/lib/arm64-v8a/libnative-lib.so
/lib/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so
/lib/x86/libnative-lib.so
/lib/x86_64/libnative-lib.so
/META-INF/...
/res/...
AndroidManifest.xml
classes.dex
resources.arsc
```

Is there anything I have to do, so the native-lib is linked?

Many thanks in advance for your support!

Kind regards 
Robert A. Fritsch

Comment: _"Compilation completed with 5 errors ..."_ you need to find where these are logged.

Comment: Your `TestClass` has `package com.example;` but your JNI call declares it as `com.pmdtec.testproject.TestClass` - these need to match. So either refactor your project or fix your JNI export name.

Comment: @Shark right, that was by editing. sorry.

Comment: @richard-critten I do not think aapt is needed. I just pointed out that I disabled it to avoid this error.

Comment: @thomas-mary I dont think this is a duplicate. The resulting libnative-lib.so in the .apk is placed in lib and therefor be linked automatically. Or am I wrong?

Comment: _" I do not think aapt is needed..."_: no, I meant it looks like your build has already failed at this point and error are logged elsewhere.  If the build has failed then running and getting loader errors are secondary.

Comment: @richard-critten after adding "android.enableAapt2=false" to the gradel.properties, the mentioned error does not occure anymore. I will add this comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone for reading my question.
It turned out, that I have to run my code on a device.
Its not possible to test navtive code via a main-method if you are using android to build it.

Kind regards
Robert A. Fritsch